# MongoDB : Is it possible to store "Data Directory" on GlusterFS Volume (across Multiple VMs), so that standby Mongo Server can use it when required?

Tags: linux, mongodb, glusterfs

I'm a newbie in MongoDB. And I'm sorry if the Question is not clear enough. What i mean is:

- I have clustered *GlusterFS Volumes* (configured on top of 2 *CentOS*). Which means, **same data directory** can be read from both CentOS boxes:
- Lets call: `CentOS-1` and `CentOS-2`
- And i wanna install MongoDB Servers `mongod` on both CentOS boxes. But start (run) only one. (The other one on `CentOS-2` might be purposely stopped)
- Then the Applications will be connecting to that one (current Active) on `CentOS-1`.

Here the main question comes in (please refer to the picture below):

- Let's say: if `CentOS-1` Server goes down, and i manually start the another MongoDB Server (`mongod` on the another box `CentOS-2`), and let all the Applications to connect to `CentOS-2`:

(1) **Will everything be still working?**
(2) Will there be 'lock' issues as in MySQL?
(3) If it works, does it mean, we can add any amount of MongoDB Servers (in stand-by mode), and whenever they swing, there's no problem?

[image]

---

Note:

### Only 1 Server at a time will be running. Not like: the Data Store is being accessed by multiple Server.

Thanks for all opinions in advanced :)

Comment: This is the reason why mongoDB has a sharding and replication feature. Why not use that?

Comment: Honestly, i don't know them. And the design above is super simple (if it works). No? :)

Comment: In your case you can delete the mongo.lock file stored in data directory (if exists) and move the whole data to second machine and run it there.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please put it in answer, so that i can set it as an proper Answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There won't be any problem in moving the data files to a different server as long as you plan to use the same version of mongodb and the same operating system. When you move the files make sure to delete the `mongodb.lock` file if it exists in data directory.

Comment: I have tried this, and confirmed simply WORKS! (The only thing to be careful is: to make sure "only one" Mongo Server is running at a time.) And upon the Server Switch-over (assumed the current one is down), just DELETE the `mongodb.lock` from another Server before starting the `mongod`. Thanks @Sarath Nair

Answer (score 0):

Glusterfs is good for file replication between various servers, but its not good idea to sync mongodb data using glusterfs.
**Will everything be still working?**
 probabily no
**Will there be 'lock' issues as in MySQL?**
    yes it will be. check this https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/faq/concurrency/  .glusterfs locks the file while it write on gluster-volumes and mongodb data may change frequently which could result problem.

you can consider mongodb replication (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/) for your purpose

Comment: Hi @anand, thanks for the answer. But i think the "concurrency" issue you highlighted occurs only when the "multiple" Mongo Servers handle the same data (if i'm not wrong). For my case (above) is different. There will always be "one server" only at one time. One Mongo Server will be accessing the Data Store. The rest Mongo Servers will be stopped. Another Mongo Server will be started only when the current one is down.

Comment: So there is no concurrent (as in realtime) i believe.

Comment: You may wish to look into this question (more simply asked question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954274/mongodb-can-the-data-store-be-used-again-in-another-different-mongo-server