# MongoDB : Can the Data Store be used again in another different Mongo Server?

Tags: mongodb, datastore

I'm a newbie in MongoDB. Please help to suggest whether it is possible, if i `COPY` the Data Store (Data Directory) of a MongoDB Instance (from 1 Server), onto another different MongoDB Server.

Which means, if i start another MongoDB Server by using the Data Store (Files) from another Server, will everything still work (especially the Data inside).

Or

Is there such a thing that, this Data Store must be operated by its original Server only?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with migrating the mongo data from one server to another. You have specific tools provided by mongoDB to do such migrations. Use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) commands for this.

Comment: But these 'tools' are usable only while it's Server is alive, is it? What if the Server is crushed .. but the File Store is on the Network Drive? (Which means file directory is still accessible) Then can it be simply picked up (copy/paste) onto newly setup Mongo Server again?

Comment: Sure you can. No problem with that. I have done this like a 100 of time :)

Comment: Yeah you can, as long as you copy the whole data directory ;)

Comment: So basically, this design (in the link) is possible, is it? http://i.stack.imgur.com/MZGgL.png

Comment: oops I cant access the page. Blocked by my company firewall

Comment: It is from my previous question. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950485/is-it-possible-to-store-mongodb-data-directory-on-glusterfs-volume-across-multi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96334/discussion-between-sarath-nair-and-).

Comment: Or you can answer in that question, please. :D